# Set default values according to JSON schema automatically

Tags: python, json, default, jsonschema

I am using the `jsonschema` package in `python` to validate my JSONs. I can set `default` in `jsonschema`. Let us assume the following schema:

```py
from jsonschema import validate

schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "key_1": {},
        "key_2": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "do_not_overwrite_if_key_exists",
        },
        "key_3": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "use_it_if_key_does_not_exist",
        },
    },
    "required": ["key_1"],
}

json_dict = {"key_1": "key_1_value", "key_2": "key_2_value"}

validate(json_dict, schema)
```

My `json_dict` is perfectly valid. I have two questions:

1. Is the `default` keyword really so "useless" as the documentation (see below) says? This is all you get?

> The “default” keyword doesn’t have an effect, but is nice to include for readers of the schema to more easily recognize the default behavior.

2. I would like to have a method that transforms my `json_dict` into the following according to the `default` keyword. Do you know of such a package?

```py
json_dict = {"key_1": "key_1_value", "key_2": "key_2_value", "key_3": "use_it_if_key_does_not_exist"}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `default` keyword is documented here: https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.9.2

It is indeed not a validation keyword, and only acts as an annotation. It is up to individual applications to decide how to use this annotation when it is generated from schema evaluation.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That is what I suspected. Would it be worth to build a package which addresses point 2 of my question?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `jsonschema_default` package linked below to generate a default JSON object from your JSON schema.
https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema-default/

Then you can use the default JSON object to fill in the missing key in your `json_dict`

Like so:

```py
import jsonschema_default as jd

default_obj = jd.create_from("./data_schema_example.json")

for key in default_obj.keys():
    if key not in json_dict:
        json_dict[key] = default_obj[key]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: AFAICS this package just creates a new JSON with the given schema defaults. Nevertheless I want a possibility to fill up a JSON where default values are missing. On the other hand, given values are not supposed to be overwritten ...

Comment: You're right.. I misread your question. What you can do is to generate the default object using `jsonschema_default` package and then use the default JSON object to fill in the missing key in your `json_dict`

Comment: I edited my original post

Answer (score 1):

The jsonschema_default solution from @ajack wouldn't work with partially filled nested objects: The key would exist thus missing default values would not be added.

Say I have this default:

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "bar_1": "value_1",
    "bar_2": "value_2"
  },
  "other": "something"
}
```

And provide this json:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar_1": "value_1"
  }
}
```

Then only `"other"` would be added with the default value. `"bar_2"` wouldn't be added because `"foo"` exists.

One solution with recursion is to search all nested structures with defaults to fill. This is my attempt of a solution:

```py
def fill_default(json_dict, schema):
    for key in schema["properties"]:
        if "properties" in schema["properties"][key].keys(): # Recursion
            if key not in json_dict.keys():
                json_dict[key] = fill_default(dict(), schema["properties"][key])
            else:
                json_dict[key] = fill_default(json_dict[key], schema["properties"][key])
            if len(json_dict[key]) == 0: #No default found inside
                del json_dict[key]
        elif key not in json_dict.keys() and "default" in schema["properties"][key].keys():
            json_dict[key] = schema["properties"][key]["default"]
    return json_dict

json_dict = fill_default(json_dict, schema)
```